# How to upload multiple files in android webview using xWalkWebView?

Tags: android

I have tried to upload multiple files via `WebChromeClient` in android lollipop.but can't able to do.so i used `third party library(CrossWalk)CrossWalk.` its fine for single uploading file.so,how to upload multiple files?

**My Code**

```
private XWalkView xWalkWebView;
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    xWalkWebView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.trigger_upload);
    xWalkWebView=(XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.crosswalk_view);
    XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);
    xWalkWebView.load("url", null);

}
public void openFileChooser(XWalkView view, final ValueCallback<Uri> uploadFile, String acceptType, String capture) {
    uploadFile.onReceiveValue(null);
}


 }
```

Comment: `I have tried to upload multiple files via WebChromeClient in android lollipop.but can't able to do.so i` Well what was the problem?

Comment: If i try to click on the button(Choose file) from webview. its nothing happen.try to search(https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220).so i moved to third part library(xWalkWebView).

Comment: Can you privide a working link?

Comment: Have a look at `onShowFileChooser` in https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/10/17/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-webview-in-l

Comment: ok....how to upload multiple files?